# C# using DataflowBlock.Completion to cancel consumer tasks instead of CancellationToken

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm wondering if there is a neat way for `IDataflowBlock.Completion` to replace needing to use a cancellation token for `ReceiveAsync` or a similar method which consumes from `BufferBlock` or another `IDataflowBlock`.

```
IDataflowBlock.ReceiveAsync<T>(TimeSpan, CancellationToken)
```

If `InputQueue` is a `BufferBlock`:

```
BufferBlock<String> InputQueue 

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)            
{
    await InputQueue.SendAsync(((char)(97 + i)).ToString());
}
```

If `InputQueue.Complete();` has been called, then when the queue is emptied and `IDataflowBlock.Completion` will change to status *RanToCompletion*, 
which can be checked with `IDataflowBlock.Completion.IsCompleted`.

If multiple threads are taking from the queue this could happen during `InputQueue.ReceiveAsync`, is there a neater alternative to handle `InputQueue` completing than:

```
try
{
    String parcel = await InputQueue.ReceiveAsync(timeSpan);
}
catch(InvalidOperationException x)
{

}
```

Comment: Your sample `try-catch` is not how you handle `Completion`. You should `await block.Completion` after calling `.Complete()`. What are actually trying to do? Also, unless you have specific reason to need to use `RecieveAsync` you should prefer using a link between blocks made by using the `LinkTo` method. [Stephen Cleary - Intro to Dataflow](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html)

Comment: I have code in which a number of producer tasks are placing packets on a bufferblock, and a number of other tasks are reading from the buffer block, the reader tasks have a token which informs them when there are no more producers loading the queue. Given that that logic is similar to the isCompleted logic, I'm looking to remove the need for the token. I'll look into linkto

Comment: Definitely look in to `LinkTo`, in `TPL-Dataflow` your consuming tasks will become either an `ActionBlock` or a `TransformBlock` depending on your needs. once they're linked you'll simply propagate completion to shut down your pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to [cancel a Dataflow Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-dataflow-block) is to provide the token to block's constructor, like this:

```
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    CancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token
});
```

[`CancellationToken` is defined in `Dataflow​Block​Options` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions?view=netcore-2.0), so even `BufferBlock` could be canceled.

Why are you implementing the `Receive` logic by yourself? Is there some restriction no to use the [`PropagateCompletion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions.aspx) with [linking your blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline#forming-the-pipeline)? For example, if your code looks like this:

```
internal void HandleMessage()
{
    try
    {
        var parcel = await InputQueue.ReceiveAsync(timeSpan);
        // handle parsel
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException x)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you simply may use the `ActionBlock` like this:

```
var InputQueue = new BufferBlock<string>();
var Handler = new ActionBlock<string>(parcel =>
{
    // handle parsel
});
var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };
InputQueue.LinkTo(Handler, linkOptions);

// now after you call Complete method for InputQueue the completion will be propagated to your Handler block:
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)            
{
    await InputQueue.SendAsync(((char)(97 + i)).ToString());
}
InputQueue.Complete();
await Handler.Completion;
```

Also note that if you need some interaction with UI, you may use your last block as [`IObservable`](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2013/01/31/mixing-tpl-dataflow-with-reactive-extensions/) with [`Rx.Net`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) library.

Comment: ok got, ActionBlock is my answer, I had consumers taking directly from by buffer block, changing this to: producers feed bufferblock, bufferblock linked to  action block/s. I'll experiment with both maxDegreeOfParallelism and bounded capacity for throttling consumers